# Writing a GeoTiff file based on a colour matrix

Tags: r, rgdal

I wonder how it may be possible to write a GTiff based on a matrix of specific colours?  This may be when the colours do not represent a quantitative variable, but rather qualitative spatial phenomena such as demographic clusters.  If I have e.g. a 1000x1000 matrix of colour values (character strings like '#FF0000'), I can easily plot these with `grid.raster(mtrx, interpolate=FALSE)` but this is difficult to overlay with other shapefiles.  I can also convert them to a SpatialPixelsDataFrame, with fieldnames 'x','y','col'.  But I'm stumped how to write either of these objects to a GTiff. For instance:

```
writeGDAL(SPDF, 'test.tif', drivername = "GTiff", colorTables=x$col)
```

yields

```
Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘gridded’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’
```

Very grateful for any pointers.

---

Example:

```
require(sp)
require(rgdal)
mtrx = matrix(rgb(runif(10000), runif(10000), runif(10000)), ncol=100)
spdf = data.frame(x=rep(1:100,100), y=rep(1:100,each=100), col=as.vector(mtrx))
plot(spdf[,1:2], col=spdf$col, pch=15)
spdf = SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points=spdf[,1:2], data=spdf)
writeGDAL(spdf, 'test.tif', drivername = "GTiff", colorTables=spdf$col)
```

Comment: Please help us help you by providing us with a reproducible example (i.e. code and example data), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for details.

Comment: Sure @Paul Hiemstra, have added to question.

Answer (score 0):

In your original call, I'm guessing that SPDF was the original data.frame, rather than a `SpatialPixelsDataFrame` that `writeGDAL` was expecting. Regardless, you have a second issue in your minimum example.

The issue is that colorTables is not expecting a data.frame: from `help(writeGDAL)`:

> default NULL, if not NULL, a **list** of length equal to the number of
>   bands, with NULL components for bands with no color table, or either
>   an **integer matrix** of red, green, blue and alpha values (0-255), or a
>   **character vector** of colours. The number of colours permitted may vary
>   with driver.

In your example, spdf$col is a factor (try `class(spdf$col)`). You can convert to a list of character vectors as requested `list(levels(spdf$col))`.

This brings up the question: what is the GeoTiff you are trying to write? Currently, it is a three band image with x, y and a character colour code... You need an actual attribute that will be coded according to a colour code.

Let's add a new attribute that is a random integer between 0 and 255, create a colour table that has a colour assigned for each value (256 values), based on your first 256 values:

```
spdf@data$new = sample(0:255, length(spdf$x), replace=TRUE)
coltable = list(levels(spdf$col)[0:255])
```

Now we can successfully write the file; note that we have to specify the type and NoData value handling to avoid errors:

```
writeGDAL(spdf[,'new'], '/Users/Benjamin/Desktop/test.tif', drivername = "GTiff", type="Byte", mvFlag=0, colorTables=coltable)
```

[image: Resulting GeoTiff image with color table applied]